# Android string comparison to EditText string value

Tags: java, android

I know this should be easy but I really don't know what i'm doing wrong.

I want to do something like this pseudocode:

```
if EditText == "ed" {show.message "Hi"}

else {show.message "NOPE"}
```

---

```
//--[Boton Sumar 2]--

public void onBT_sumar2Click(View v) {

    EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_1);
    EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_2);
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV_resultado);

    if (e1.getText().equals("ed")){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = ":V / hi :V /" ;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

    }

    else {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "NOPE";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I always get the message "NOPE"

Comment: where do you set the text for the `TextView`?

Comment: In the TextView "ET_1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be converting the value of `e1` to a string for use of comparison.

Try:

`if (e1.getText().toString().equals("ed")) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

e1.getText() returns an Editable object. Since you are trying to compare a string against a different type of object this expression evaluates to not equal, will always return false, and NOPE will be shown.

You have to get the string value from the Editable object using the toString() method.